# Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused

Tags: 12.04, connection

I am running 25 scrapy jobs, each has 50 concurrent requests on a heavy machine (with Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS). I am using proxies to send requests. After 15 minutes or so, I get this error from almost all of the requests:

```
Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
```

I contacted the proxy service provider and they say that this problem is from handling sockets on my side.

So my scripts send 1250 concurrent requests. Is there anyway I could find out where the problem is? Is there a connection limit on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I did a small amount of research on this and i've found a very similar thread on serverfault [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/10852/what-limits-the-maximum-number-of-connections-on-a-linux-server). It seems that your kernel might be a limiting factor in this particular case, as such a high amount of concurrent connections is not very common. The accepted answer states it might be due to the ip_conntrack table overflowing.

On Ubuntu (Server) a fix could be setting some custom parameters in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max = 32768
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_orphan_retries = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 25
net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans = 8192
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 32768    61000
```

Please take a look at the thread I linked to, and always be **very careful** with custom configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try running your spider as superuser. I was running the spider directly with the command `scrapy runspider`, when I just tried executing it with:

`sudo scrapy runspider`

it worked.